# SQL command not properly ended for Union All

Tags: sql, oracle11g, union-all

I'm having trouble understanding the error on my code. Could somebody help me out?

Here's my sql query

```
SELECT S.SUBSTR(ASSIGNED_NUMBER, -4) FROM (
   SELECT SUBSTR(ASSIGNED_NUMBER, -4) AS SDATE FROM TBL_DATA1 GROUP BY SUBSTR(ASSIGNED_NUMBER, -4)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT SUBSTR(ASSIGNED_NUMBER, -4) AS SDATE FROM TBL_DATA2 GROUP BY SUBSTR(ASSIGNED_NUMBER, -4)
) AS S GROUP BY S.SUBSTR(ASSIGNED_NUMBER, -4);
```

`Note: Originally, My outer column is S.SDATE and edited it to S.SUBSTR(ASSIGNED_NUMBER, -4)`.

Output:

`ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"`

By the way, the sample date in my `ASSIGNED_NUMBER` column is `58-2016`.
I use substring to get the 2016

Comment: You are using wrong column in the outer query select

Comment: Besides other issues pointed out in comments and answers, you have `S.SUBSTR(ASSIGNED_NUMBER)` where you probably meant to have `SUBSTR(S.ASSIGNED_NUMBER)`. The query alias `S` should be attached right before the column name, not before the name of the function `SUBSTR`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using S.SUBSTR(ASSIGNED_NUMBER, -4) when you have given the columns in the subquery alias of SDATE.

Also, when using subquery the naming should be `) s` not `) AS S`

Your query should be

```
SELECT S.SDATE FROM (
   SELECT SUBSTR(ASSIGNED_NUMBER, -4) AS SDATE FROM TBL_DATA1 GROUP BY SUBSTR(ASSIGNED_NUMBER, -4)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT SUBSTR(ASSIGNED_NUMBER, -4) AS SDATE FROM TBL_DATA2 GROUP BY SUBSTR(ASSIGNED_NUMBER, -4)
) S GROUP BY S.SDATE;
```

Comment: That's my original code, I just changed it, but it returned the same error.

Comment: I see, you made it. Thanks sir!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT S.SDATE FROM (
   SELECT SUBSTR(ASSIGNED_NUMBER, -4) AS SDATE FROM TBL_DATA1 GROUP BY SUBSTR(ASSIGNED_NUMBER, -4)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT SUBSTR(ASSIGNED_NUMBER, -4) AS SDATE FROM TBL_DATA2 GROUP BY SUBSTR(ASSIGNED_NUMBER, -4)
)  S GROUP BY S.SDATE;
```

Comment: That's my original code, I just changed it, but it returned the same error.

Comment: Are you able to produce output with the inner query?

Comment: yes. the two queries inside are working. I'm trying to combine the outputs using union all, but did'nt work.

Comment: Okay so your Union all query doesnt work at the first place? Just wanted to confirm...

Comment: It works now based on Marcus H answer. Thank you sir for your response.

Comment: In Oracle `as` cannot be used before a table or subquery alias. It can only be used before a column alias (and even there it is optional). Used with table or query alias will throw an error.